# NextJS throws error on Firebase Functions Deploy

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, next.js

TLDR; I'm following an example from NextJS using Firebase, and with minimal change I can't push to Firebase.

I am following the NextJS [with-firebase-hosting-and-typescript](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting-and-typescript) example, and in accordance with the help from [#8893](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/8893).

I changed the `deploy` script in `package.json` to `cross-env NODE_ENV=production firebase deploy`.

I also changed the `conf` value in `functions/index.ts` to

```
conf: {
    distDir: `${path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname)}/../functions/next`
}
```

When I go to deploy the app to firebase I now receive an error

> Deployment error.
>   Error setting up the execution environment for your function. Please try deploying again after a few minutes.

I did some debugging and if I comment out the line

```
const app = next({ dev, conf: { distDir: `${path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname)}/../functions/next` } 
})
```

in `functions/index.ts`, then the functions will deploy just fine.  So, the issue seems to be with `next()`

Here is code of the `functions/index.ts`, this throws the error.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import next from 'next'
import * as path from 'path'



const appSetup = { 
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production', 
  conf: { distDir: `${path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname)}/../functions/next` } 
}
console.log("appSetup: ", appSetup)
const app = next(appSetup)
// const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

export const nextApp = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
  // return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res))
  return res.send({ status: "Hello from Firebase!, nextApp" })
})
```

Here is code of the `functions/index.ts`, this DOES NOT throw an error

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'
import next from 'next'
import * as path from 'path'



const appSetup = { 
  dev: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production', 
  conf: { distDir: `${path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname)}/../functions/next` } 
}
console.log("appSetup: ", appSetup)
// const app = next(appSetup)
// const handle = app.getRequestHandler()

export const nextApp = functions.https.onRequest(async(req, res) => {
  // return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res))
  return res.send({ status: "Hello from Firebase!, nextApp" })
})
```

in `package.json`

```
"firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.6.0",
"next": "^9.3.5",
"react": "16.13.1",
"react-dom": "16.13.1"
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please do no show pictures of text or code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson Sorry, this is now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone struggling with the same issue. The fix was the line in `functions/index.ts`

I needed to replace

```
conf: { distDir: `${path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname)}/../functions/next` }
```

to

```
conf: { distDir: `${path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname)}/next` }
```